# starting external process when one process is done

Tags: c#, vb.net, process.start

Stupid question, but I am starting a couple external applications `(all .exe)`. After the process is started, how can I make my program wait until that process ends to start another process?

Example'

```
'Start application
 Process.Start(My.Computer.FileSystem.CurrentDirectory & "SomeEXE1.exe")

**' A if statement or something to state that SomeEXE2.exe will NOT start until SomeEXE1.exe finish.**

 Process.Start(My.Computer.FileSystem.CurrentDirectory & "SomeEXE2.exe")
```

Answer (score 2):

Just call:

```
Process.WaitForExit
```

on that instance of `Process`.

Answer (score 0):

How about using Shell?

Dim pID As Integer = Shell(thePathOfEXE, AppWinStyle.NormalFocus, True, 30000)

Will launch the exe passing the processID back to pID, normal focus and wait until completed execution or until 30 seconds have passed. The 30000 could be -1 if you're not interested in a timeout.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xe736fyk(v=vs.71).aspx